# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - October 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 13th edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for October 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              300
2   nohillside                250
3   Tetsujin                  190
4   jaume                     170
5   Monomeeth                 160
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 850.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,803 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2018-10-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   abc                       127
2   IconDaemon                 89
3   Nimesh Neema               76
4   Buscar웃                   64
5   bmike                      56
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,385
2   Monomeeth                 279
3   Buscar웃                  253
4   bmike                     200
5   Nimesh Neema              175
```

A big thank you to all 77 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>**Note:** Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 55
2   jaume                      37
3   Nimesh Neema               36
4   Mark                       31
5   Mark                       29
```

A big thank you to all 21 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

<sup>**NOTE:** The user "Mark" listed in 4th and 5th spots are separate users.</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   jaume                     223
2   Nimesh Neema              195
3   Monomeeth                 164
4   abc                       126
5   fsb                       117
```

A big thank you to all 35 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                  88
2   Nimesh Neema               34
3   Tetsujin                   33
4   Allan                      31
5   Mark                       30
```

A big thank you to all 27 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Tetsujin                   39
2   Nimesh Neema               25
3   jaume                      24
4   Allan                      23
5   nohillside                 22
```

A big thank you to all 22 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 12
2   Tetsujin                    8
3   jaume                       7
4   Nimesh Neema, Mark          6
5   bmike                       5
```

A big thank you to all 14 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               31
2   nohillside, Monomeeth      22
3   grg                        21
4   Allan, jaume               15
5   bmike, Glorfindel, abc     12
```

A big thank you to all 39 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [What does a .dmg verify?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338257/what-does-a-dmg-verify)

   - Posted by: 2br-2b
   - Votes: **32**
2. [Is using both wireless/wired charging simultaneously for an iPhone faster?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340981/is-using-both-wireless-wired-charging-simultaneously-for-an-iphone-faster)

   - Posted by: scohe001
   - Votes: **28**
3. [“Hold Cmd-Q to Quit” from Chrome](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340508/hold-cmd-q-to-quit-from-chrome)

   - Posted by: Solar Mike
   - Votes: **24**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [LibreOffice doesn't have an icon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338852/168832)

   - Posted by: nohillside
   - Votes: **71**
2. [LibreOffice doesn't have an icon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338862/168832)

   - Posted by: Ruslan
   - Votes: **64**
3. [Is using both wireless/wired charging simultaneously for an iPhone faster?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/340983/168832)

   - Posted by: Kevin Grabher
   - Votes: **54**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Received an email saying someone has hacked my email account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340295/received-an-email-saying-someone-has-hacked-my-email-account)

   - Posted by: sam utting
   - Views: **11,669**
2. [Is it a good practice to create a desktop shortcut on mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338917/is-it-a-good-practice-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-on-mac)

   - Posted by: Mozfox
   - Views: **7,632**
3. [LibreOffice doesn't have an icon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338849/libreoffice-doesnt-have-an-icon)

   - Posted by: nylypej
   - Views: **6,410**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Housemd](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93225/housemd)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [abc](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/173522/abc)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [jaume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/32815/jaume)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [2br-2b](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/304445/2br-2b)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [sam utting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/307186/sam-utting)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In October our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned **511 flags** with an average handling time of **22 minutes**. In summary, we also:

- deleted 444 comments
- deleted 325 posts
- closed 162 posts
- edited 153 posts
- created 70 posts
- created 500 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)